# Replace ~ in line number column

Tags: vim

For some reason this annoys me to no extent and I don't know why. Any google searches result in text-replacements.

When you open a file you if you have `set number` set you see numbers of each line of your code and when  your code/file ends you see ~ like so:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
~
~
~
```

Is it possible to replace ~ with - or something else ?

Comment: There's no configuration for this (I think it dates back to vi); you'd have to patch and recompile Vim yourself.

Comment: Is it possible to have numbers go down to the height of the file ? Even if I only have 30 lines of code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:hi NonText guifg=bg`

This will set the color of non text characters to be the same as the background. However, this may affect more than just the end of file `~` characters (to see the characters use `:h hl-NonText`).

There is no other way to disable them.

Comment: I set it to this but they still appear. I either want to change them or possibly have number line go to full height of the screen.

Comment: `hi NonText ctermfg=bg´ set these if you run your vim in the terminal